# preg_match_all - Extract key / value from template

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am storing the following in a mysql database:

```
%URL% https://google.com
%TEXT% Hello world!
%LARGETEXT% Hello
My name is ...
I am from ...
```

My goal is to make the strings which are wrapped in % to PHP array keys and the string besides are the values.

The problem is, that my regex does not extract the multiline strings.

Here is the code:

```
preg_match_all ("/%(\w+)%(.*)/", $msg, $matches);
```

It does output:

```
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "BASIC"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "TEXT"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "LARGETEXT"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) " https://google.de"
    [1]=>
    string(13) " Hello world!"
    [2]=>
    string(6) " Hello"
  }
```

At the second array only 'Hello' is shown, instead of:

```
Hello
My name is ...   
I am from ...
```

I tryed various regex but i come always to the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
~%(\w+)%(.*?)(?=%\w+%|$)~s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsHDqn/1)

**Details**

- `%` - a percent sign
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `%` - a percent sign
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars (note that `s` modifier will let `.` match line break chars, too) as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of...
- `(?=%\w+%|$)` - `%`, 1+ word chars, `%` or end of string.

An identical *unrolled* expression (more efficient one) will look like

```
~%(\w+)%([^%]*(?:%(?!\w+%)[^%]*)*)~
```

(no need for the `s` modifier). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsHDqn/2).

The `[^%]*(?:%(?!\w+%)[^%]*)*` matches any 0+ chars other than `%`, and then matches 0 or more consequent occurrences of `%` not followed with 1+ word chars and then `%` followed with any 0+ chars other than `%`.

**If your entries always appear at the beginning of different lines** you may use

```
~^%(\w+)%(.*?)(?=^%\w+%|\z)~sm
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsHDqn/3)

**Details**

- `^` - matches the start of a *line* (due to `m` modifier)
- `%(\w+)%` - matches `%`, then matches and captures into Group 1 one or more word chars, then matches `%`
- `(.*?)` - matches and captures into Group 2 any 0+ chars as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of...
- `(?=^%\w+%|\z)` - start of a line, `%`, 1+ word chars, `%` OR the very end of string (`\z` might be replaced with `\Z` here since just end of string position is enough).

Unrolled version:

```
~^%(\w+)%(.*(?:\R(?!%\w+%).*)*)~m
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsHDqn/4). The `(.*(?:\R(?!%\w+%).*)*)` part matches the following into Group 2:

- `.*` - the rest of the line after `%`, 1+ word chars, `%` substring
- `(?:\R(?!%\w+%).*)*` - matches 0+ consecutive occurrences of:

  - `\R(?!%\w+%)` - a line break sequence (`\R`) that has no `%`, 1+ word chars and a `%` after it  and then...
  - `.*` -  any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the end of line.

Comment: The two patterns are wrong. What if you have a URL with special characters replaced with there hexadecimal representations like: `http://domain.tld/fo%20%20lder/index.php?path=http%3A%2F%2Fotherdomain.tld`? Instead of using `%` you should use the newline.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: You can't say the patterns are *wrong*, I suggested the pattern based on the original pattern that *didn't* rely on the line breaks. It is easy to add anchors and a MULTILINE modifier to the first regex to fix it, and then it can be easily unrolled.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte going by OP's specifications, i'd argue, here the string `20` is actually wrapped in `%%`, and would thus be a key. no exceptions to this rule was written.

Answer (score 1):

a regex-free approach:

```
$str=explode('%',$str);
$arr=[];
for($i=1;$i<count($str);$i+=2){
    $arr[$str[$i]]=trim($str[$i+1]);
}
var_dump($arr);
```

[seems to work fine.](https://3v4l.org/GCsGn) (remove the `trim` if you actually want to keep the newlines though.. i just assumed you didn't)